# how to merge two unequal size data frame in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
>temp

      Var1                Freq1
1   file-upload             1
2   image-processing        1
3     mime-types            1
4       php                 5


>top 

        Var2               Freq2
1   file-upload             1
2   image-processing        1
3     mime-types            1
4       php                 5
5      upload               1
6      firefox              2
7   machine-learning        1
8     matlab                1
9        r                  2
10      c#                  7
```

Now I am doing:

```
m1 <- merge(temp, top, by.x = "Var1", by.y = "Var2", all.x = TRUE)
```

Them `m1` will be:

```
       Var1               Freq1        Freq2
1   file-upload             1            1
2   image-processing        1            1
3     mime-types            1            1
4       php                 5            5
```

but the number of levels of `m1$Var1` is showing 10 not 4 and when I am trying to do a split of `m1` based on the Values of `Var1`

```
x <- split(m1, m1$Var1)
```

The length(x) is 10 not 4 and the 6 elements are showing this kind of values

```
$c#
[1] Var1 Freq1  Freq2  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I want to remove these elements from the list or is there any way that when i am merging I have the number of level equal to that of temp df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove empty levels by

```
m1$Var1 <- factor(m1$Var1)
```

Comment: thanks it worked...but is there any way that t can be discarded when we r doing merging???

Comment: I don't think so - unless you set up, in temp and top,   Var1 to be a character vector rather than a factor

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `droplevels` around the `merge` to remove unused levels:

```
x <- data.frame(var=letters[1:3],freq1=1:3)
y <- data.frame(var=letters[2:4],freq2=2:4)

merge(x,y)$var
[1] b c
Levels: a b c

droplevels(merge(x,y))$var
[1] b c
Levels: b c
```